# 1: command not found

Tags: bash, variables, numbers, set, sh

I'm writing a divides-by-three function in Bash, and it won't let me set a variable to a number.

fizzy.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

div3() {
    return `$1 % 3 -eq 0`
}

d=div3 1
echo $d
```

Example:

```
$ ./fizzy.sh 
./fizzy.sh: line 7: 1: command not found
```

Comment: Your `div3` function does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Just for the record / google searchers ==> This isn't the case here, but you get the exact same error if you accidentally add in spaces around the equal sign, `d = div3 1` vs the correct `d=div3 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash functions normally "return" values by printing them to standard output, where the caller can capture them using

```
`func args ...`
```

or

```
$(func args ...)
```

This makes functions work like external commands.

The `return` statement, on the other hand, sets the value of `$?`.  Normally that's going to be set to 0 for success, 1 for failure, or some other value for a specified kind of failure.  Think of it as a status code, not a general value.  It's likely that this will only support values from 0 to 255.

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

div3() {
    expr $1 % 3 = 0   # prints "0" or "1"
}

d=$(div3 1)
echo $d
```

Note that I've also changed the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) from `#!/usr/bin/env sh` to `#!/bin/sh`.  The `#!/usr/bin/env` trick is often used when invoking an interpreter (such as `perl`) that you want to locate via `$PATH`.  But in this case, `sh` will *always* be in `/bin/sh` (the system would break in various ways if it weren't).  The only reason to write `#!/usr/bin/env sh` would be if you wanted to use whatever `sh` command happens to appear first in your `$PATH` rather than the standard one.  Even in that case you're probably better of specifying the path to `sh` directly.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
 d=div3 1
```

line is the culprit because you assign the string div3 to the env variable d and try to execute 1. To avoid this, use backticks to assign the result of the evaluation instead:

```
 d=`div3 1`
```

Then, another error occurs in your evaluation function. You need to run test on your arguments instead of trying to evaluate them as a command:

```
return `test $(($1 % 3)) -eq 0`
```

Still no output, but no errors either. What would your expected output be, actually?

Comment: @MattBall: I did as well, there was a masked error there. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
div3() {
    return $(( ( $1 % 3 ) == 0 ))
}

d=$(div3 1)
rc=$?

echo $d
echo $rc


(blank line)
0
```

Note, return just sets the value of $? for the function
to return value, just print it.

```
div3() {
    printf $(( ( $1 % 3 ) == 0 )) "\n"
}
```