# Bash always printing same value regardless of boolean value

Tags: bash, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

Related to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002083/1-command-not-found/8002330#8002330).

fizzy.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

div3() {
    expr $1 % 3 = 0
}

div5() {
    expr $1 % 5 = 0
}

fizzy() {
    if [ $(div3 $1) ] && [ $(div5 $1) ]; then
        expr "FizzBuzz"
    elif [ $(div3 $1) ]; then
        expr "Fizz"
    elif [ $(div5 $1) ]; then
        expr "Buzz"
    else
        expr "$1"
    fi
}

echo $(fizzy 1)
echo $(fizzy 2)
echo $(fizzy 3)
```

Example:

```
$ ./fizzy.sh
FizzBuzz
FizzBuzz
FizzBuzz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expr $1 % 3 = 0` yields 1 or 0, depending on whether the result of `$1 % 3` is zero or not, but `if` treats 0 as true, not false.

```
sh-3.2$ if [ 0 ]; then echo ok; fi
ok
```

So you'd need to compare the output of your function against 1. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

div3() {
    expr $1 % 3 = 0
}

div5() {
    expr $1 % 5 = 0
}

fizzy() {
    if [ $(div3 $1) -eq 1 ] && [ $(div5 $1) -eq 1 ]; then
        expr "FizzBuzz"
    elif [ $(div3 $1) -eq 1 ]; then
        expr "Fizz"
    elif [ $(div5 $1) -eq 1 ]; then
        expr "Buzz"
    else
        expr "$1"
    fi
}

for (( i = 1; i <= 15; i++ ))
do
    echo $(fizzy $i)
done
```

Comment: The `if [ 0 ]; ...` test isn't doing what you think it is. You get the same result with `if [ 1 ]` or `if [ cow ]` or any non-empty string. This will demonstrate what you want: `if $(exit 0); then echo Y; else echo N; fi` and test again with 1 intead of 0

Answer (score 1):

Without the need for div3 or div5 functions.

```
fizzbuzz() { # eg: fizzbuzz 10
   ((($1%15==0))&& echo FizzBuzz)||
   ((($1%5==0))&& echo Buzz)||
   ((($1%3==0))&& echo Fizz)||
   echo $1;
}
```

Or you could do it all at once

```
fizzbuzz() { # eg: fizzbuzz
for i in {1..100};
do
   ((($i%15==0))&& echo FizzBuzz)||
   ((($i%5==0))&& echo Buzz)||
   ((($i%3==0))&& echo Fizz)||
   echo $i;
done;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is bash, you don't need to call out to `expr`:

```
div3() { (( $1 % 3 == 0 )); }
div5() { (( $1 % 5 == 0 )); }

fizzbuzz() {
  if div3 $1 && div5 $1; then
    echo FizzBuzz
  elif div3 $1; then
    echo Fizz
  elif div5 $1; then
    echo Buzz
  else
    echo
  fi
}

for ((n=10; n<=15; n++)); do
  printf "%d\t%s\n" $n $(fizzbuzz $n)
done
```

Comment: Almost. I want fizzbuzz to be a function.

Comment: It shouldn't't be difficult to take what I've given you and write a function from it. It would essentially be the `if` statement.

Comment: Nothing about Bash syntax is easy or intuitive. If I could have rewritten this as a function, I would have done so.